Prep RHEL/Rocky Template for Virtualisation - Resetting network config and setting
I'm working on creating a template for RHEL/Rocky Linux 9 that I'll use to deply new VMs.
As part of the prep phase I remove UUID and HWADDDR settings from the nmconnection profile under /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ like this:
#Clean out UUID and HWAADDR in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections /bin/sed -i '/^\(HWADDR\|UUID\)=/Id' /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*nmconnection
This works flawlessly, and after a few more steps I shut down the VM, convert it into a template for further use. This is according to the references I find regarding manually creating VM templates.
When I create a new VM it comes up as intended. When I run the command '''nmcli connection show''' the connection has still the same uuid and the nmconnection file has no new uuid:
NAME  UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE
lan   bb093c6c-944c-34f1-ad26-20ea3c85d995  ethernet  ens18
lo    1ed4fc3a-12b8-4bea-af88-e252cc152e95  loopback  lo

Am I missing something or is this as intended?
/DD

connectivity is MAC-based, UUID is local to the server - I don't think you have to worry about it.
If you wish - try removing said UUID from *nmconnection and restarting the server, then check what will nmcli connection show.
Regards
Mike
